# Splitting a coordinate string into X and Y columns with a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop, indexing

So I created a pandas data frame showing the coordinates for an event and number of times those coordinates appear, and the coordinates are shown in a string like this.

```
      Coordinates  Occurrences   x
0     (76.0, -8.0)           1   0
1   (-41.0, -24.0)           1   1
2     (69.0, -1.0)           1   2
3     (37.0, 30.0)           1   3
4     (-60.0, 1.0)           1   4
..             ...         ...  ..
63  (-45.0, -11.0)           1  63
64    (80.0, -1.0)           1  64
65    (84.0, 24.0)           1  65
66     (76.0, 7.0)           1  66
67   (-81.0, -5.0)           1  67
```

I want to create a new data frame that shows the x and y coordinates individually and shows their occurrences as well like this--

```
 x    Occurrences y  Occurrences
    76      ...     -8       ...
   -41      ...     -24      ...
    69      ...     -1       ...
    37      ...     -30      ...
    60      ...      1       ...
```

I have tried to split the string but don't think I am doing it correctly and don't know how to add it to the table regardless--I think I'd have to do something like a for loop later on in my code--I scraped the data from an API, here is the code to set up the data frame shown.

```
for key in contents['liveData']['plays']['allPlays']:
    # for plays in key['result']['event']:
        # print(key)
    if (key['result']['event'] == "Shot"):
        #print(key['result']['event'])
        scoordinates = (key['coordinates']['x'], key['coordinates']['y'])
        if scoordinates not in shots:
            shots[scoordinates] = 1
        else:
            shots[scoordinates] += 1
    if (key['result']['event'] == "Goal"):
        #print(key['result']['event'])
        gcoordinates = (key['coordinates']['x'], key['coordinates']['y'])
        if gcoordinates not in goals:
            goals[gcoordinates] = 1
        else:
            goals[gcoordinates] += 1     
            
#create data frame using pandas
gdf = pd.DataFrame(list(goals.items()),columns = ['Coordinates','Occurences'])
print(gdf)
sdf = pd.DataFrame(list(shots.items()),columns = ['Coordinates','Occurences'])
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import re
df[['x', 'y']] = df.Coordinates.apply(lambda c: pd.Series(dict(zip(['x', 'y'], re.findall('[-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', c.strip())))))
```

Answer (score 1):

using the in-built string methods to achieve this should be performant:

```
df[["x", "y"]] = df["Coordinates"].str.strip(r"[()]").str.split(",", expand=True).astype(np.float)
```

(this also converts x,y to float values, although not requested probably desired)